# Rails 4 json return on API

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json, api, return

I'm creating an API on my application. I currently overrided the `as_json` method in my model in order to be able to get attached files as well as logo from Paperclip :

```
def as_json( options = {} )
  super.merge(logo_small: self.logo.url(:small), logo_large: self.logo.url(:large), taxe: self.taxe, attachments: self.attachments)
end
```

Then within my controller, I'm doing :

```
def index
  @products = current_user.products
  respond_with @products
end

def show
  respond_with @product
end
```

The problem is that on the index, I don't want get all the attachments. I only need it on the show method. So I tried it :

```
def index
  @products = current_user.products
  respond_with @products, except: [:attachments]
end
```

But unfortunately it's only working on default product attributes (everyting that I merged seems not to be consider). How can I do to not send `:attachments`?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd recommend you have a look at [active_model_serializers](https://github.com/rails-api/active_model_serializers). It will provide a nice and OOP way of handling the kind of object decoration you need - selectively excluding attributes - and much more. There's even a [Railscast](http://railscasts.com/episodes/409-active-model-serializers)!

Comment: Thanks. Using it makes it more flexible, indeed. However, I still didn't find the way to send associations wether I'm in `index` or `show` action per se, as the serializer is always sending the same data. All I can do is sending depending on user level. Any ideas?

Comment: Two suggestions: A) Create two different serializers, one for each use case, and select it in the controller like ``render json: @objects, each_serializer: ObjectWithAssociationSerializer, status: 200``. B) have a look at this issue on the gem: https://github.com/rails-api/active_model_serializers/issues/331. It helped me in the past for a similar use case.

Comment: Thanks a lot. Sounds like a possible solution to my problem till it's full support by the gem. Will digg into it :) Thanks mate